# VB.NET HttpWebRequest POST

Tags: vb.net, authentication, httpwebrequest

Hey whhat's up. I've been looking at some example source codes but I can't quite figure it out. I'd like to send a POST request to login to a website with my account. For an example, how would I login to this website using HttpWebRequest..

http://z4.invisionfree.com/cotec/index.php?

It's for an application I'm building for my clan where you have to have an account on the forum to open the application, so if the login works it opens.

Answer (score 3):

There's a decent tutorial for HTTPWebRequest POST methods and a login example here:
http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-51-httpwebrequest-post-method/

Answer (score 2):

```
dim email as string = "your email"
dim pass as string = "your pass"

    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://touch.facebook.com"), HttpWebRequest)
                postReq.Method = "GET"
                postReq.KeepAlive = True
                postReq.CookieContainer = logincookie
                postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3"

                Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                logincookie.Add(postresponse.Cookies)

                Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

                Dim infos As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

                '---------------------------

                Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes("lsd=&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&version=1&ajax=0&width=0&pxr=0&gps=0&m_ts=&li=&email=" & email.Replace("@", "%40") & "&pass=" & pass & "&login=Connexion")

                postReq = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://touch.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Ftouch.facebook.com%2F&refid=8"), HttpWebRequest)
                postReq.Method = "POST"
                postReq.KeepAlive = True
                postReq.CookieContainer = logincookie
                postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                postReq.Referer = "https://touch.facebook.com/"
                postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3"
                postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

                Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
                postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
                postreqstream.Close()

                postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                logincookie.Add(postresponse.Cookies)

                postreqreader = New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not leverage this bit of code to simplify your effort: http://joel.net/code/easyhttp.aspx

Comment: So how would I use the class to send a login request?
EasyHttp.Send("http://z4.invisionfree.com/cotec/index.php?", "username=USER&password=PASS")
Just that?

Comment: You could yes.  Just make sure that whatever the form fields are named you specify them in the fashion you show.